How to trigger event based on new updates on DB using hangfire
I'm in a situation where I want to trigger some background job using hangfire. I don't want to trigger the event based on cron (each period of time) but I want it to get triggered when there are new changes.
In my table, for example when new record is added I want hangfire to trigger the background process. Is this possible? If yes ,please adivse if there's any resource I can refer to?
my current code is like this :
_backgroundJobClient.Schedule(() => _epcProcess.EPCProcessStart(transactionId), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

recurring each hour
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IBackgroundOperations>(x => x.ProcessNewTransactions(), "0 * * * *");

and my expectations is to schedule based on new changes on table

You can enqueue the job after the insert in the database and schedule job, or recuring job. There is no mechanism other than that in hangfire.

I was able to do this by essentially reverse engineering the table setup in Hangfire and wrote a stored procedure that would create any new Scheduled Job.  I cannot share that code unfortunately.  I did it by having a unit test that scheduled a job and looking in the tables to see what that job looked like just after being scheduled.

not not out of the box - you can have recuring job that will run every hour and check the database. Or you can enqueue the job after inserting something in the database.
